# Does ignite ClientCache of thin client support distributed locks

Tags: locking, distributed, ignite, clientcache

Now i am using ignite ClientCache of thin client, I didn't find distributed locks of ClientCache, if I want to use distributed locks,I must use Ignition.start()

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the thin-client is currently a way of accessing data in an Ignite cluster. If you want to do more sophisticated things, such as compute or locking, you'll need to use a thick client.